# array.splice vs setting a value to null

Tags: javascript, arrays

> You should use `array.splice(i, 1);` instead of `array[i] = null` This will preserve the keys in the array

Source : [Should I bother cleaning array in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33388729/should-i-bother-cleaning-array-in-node-js)

I don't really understand this sentence. Why `array[i] = null` will change the keys of the array ? Why `array.splice(i, 1);` is better ?

Comment: See also [JavaScript Array Delete Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements)

Comment: It is not better at all. All depends what is the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: If you want to squeeze out performance then setting it to null is the better option (V8 optimizes arrays, and fiddling with the indices prevents it from optimizing it properly). If you need to remove an item from an array then using `splice` is the way to go. Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array.splice(i, 1);` will remove the element from array, so changing the `length` of array.

Whereas `array[i] = null` will just set the value at the index `i` to `null` and will not alter the array length. This is same as `delete array[i]` except the `delete` operator will set the value at the index to `undefined`.

Regarding

> Why `array[i] = null` will change the keys of the array?

I think there is missing a word *not* in between the will and change.

So, according to me, it should be

> Why `array[i] = null` will **not** change the keys(or rather *length*) of the array?

Second question:

> Why `array.splice(i, 1);` is better?

It alters the `length` of the array by removing the element from it. So, when iterating over array you don't have to check `if(value == null)`.

Which one to use totally depends on the use-case.

Comment: So i believe `splice` is not really better. Just a different usage. Thanks.

Comment: @Magus: In fact, `splice` is magnitudes slower, because it has to adjust all the indices.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to see the differences in behaviour with a simple test case.  This is what Chrome outputs from the console:

```
var test = ['a','b','c']
test[1] = null
["a", null, "c"]

var test = ['a','b','c']
test.splice(1, 1)
["a", "c"]

var test = ['a','b','c']
delete test[1]
["a", undefined × 1, "c"]
```

As you can see, splice is the only one to change the index of `c` from 2 to 1.

Which one you want to use depends on your use case.  There may be a case where you have a fixed-length array, and you want to remove an item without affecting the index of items after it, in which case splicing would be inappropriate.